# Lines that debugger visited

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

Do you know some plug-in to visual studio , that can remember lines and the order in which they where visited in the debug mode ?

And I will be able to compare two different runs  of the debugger in it  ?

Something like the stack in the debugger, but remembers all the data in line file and the order and can be viewed later and compared .

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called [Historical Debugger](http://blogs.msdn.com/ianhu/archive/2009/05/13/historical-debugging-in-visual-studio-team-system-2010.aspx), but you'll have to wait for Visual Studio 2010.

Take a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/methodlogger.aspx) project. It can log all method calls.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a plugin for VS2008 however:

You can copy the call stack from within the stack window in Visual Studio and paste that say to say word. This includes line numbers. You could use this together with source control. You would just need to annotate the word docs so you could match them with the version of code in your source control.